# OpenNN assertion with MNIST sample

Tags: eigen, tensor, opennn

I try to let the MNIST sample run with the actual OpenNN. In convolutionallayer.cpp, line 435

const Tensor<type, 2> deltas_times_derivatives = deltas * convolutional_layer_forward_propagation->activations_derivatives;

activations_derivatives has dimemsions 4, so TensorEvaluator asserts.

The following loops need only slices. And deltas is a TensorMap, line 433.

Does anybody know how to use this?